How to Securely Upload Multiple SSL Certificates on remote server with CircleCI and Docker
I'm working on a DevOps workflow using CircleCI for deployments and Docker for containerized applications.
I need to automate uploading Let's Encrypt SSL certificates (multiple certificates possible) to a remote server where an Nginx reverse proxy is running.
CircleCI doesn't allow direct file storage within workflows.
Managing multiple certificates with environment variables becomes cumbersome.
I'm looking for a secure and automated way to upload the SSL certificate files (cert.pem, chain.pem, fullchain.pem, privkey.pem) to the remote server during deployments using CircleCI and use it in my Nginx Docker container.
How can I achieve secure and automated upload of multiple SSL certificates to the remote server for use with Nginx reverse proxy within a CircleCI workflow?
I would appreciate it if the workflow could be set up in a way to auto-renew certificates using certbot.
